# Angular ui routers nested ui-views not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a simple nested route within angular and whenever a nested route occurs the view doesn't pop up

With a path of `http://localhost:9000/#/home/hello` I still only see  `homeHello`

Why isn't the nested ui view picking up the home.hello template?

### Rendered HTML

```
<section ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
  <section class="home ng-scope">
    home
    <a ui-sref=".hello" href="#/home/hello">Hello</a>
    <!-- uiView: ui-view -->
    <div ui-view="ui-view" class="ng-scope"></div>
  </section>
</section>
```

### Angular Ui Router

```
// app.js

angular.module('spoonFeeder',
  ['ui.router',
   'ngAnimate',
   'ngCookies',
   'ngResource',
   'ngSanitize',
   'ngTouch'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
        })
        .state('home.hello', {
            url: '/hello',
            templateUrl: 'home/hello.html'
        })

        // use the HTML5 History API
        // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

### Views

```
<!-- home/home`.html -->
<section class="home">home<a ui-sref=".hello">Hello</a>
  <div ui-view="ui-view"></div>
</section>

<!-- home/hello.html -->
<section class="hello">Hello</section>
```

Comment: Your ui-sref on your child state should include the parent. e.g. ```ui-sref="home.hello"``` AFAIK

Comment: It doesn't need to this is relative pathing. even with it on there it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nK8zLLidwjTAUe3kEwFZ?p=preview) with a working example. What I changed was: "extending of the parent template"

```
<section class="home">home
  <a ui-sref=".hello">Hello</a>
  <div ui-view="ui-view"></div>
  <div ui-view=""></div>      <!-- new line -->
</section>
```

The new element `div` does contain also attribute `ui-view`, but in this case, it is unnamed so this state definition can find it:

```
.state('home.hello', {
  url: '/hello',
  templateUrl: 'tpl.hello.html',
})
```

To show, how we can target the first one `ui-view="ui-view"`, which is in fact named, there is new state Hello2:

```
.state('home.hello2', {
  url: '/hello2',
  views : {
    'ui-view' : {
      templateUrl: 'tpl.hello2.html',
    }
  }
})
```

and this state, is now really targeting the named `ui-view="ui-view`, because it uses explicit `views {}` defintion. The state hello, on the other hand uses implicit views definition which could be expressed like this:

```
  views : {
    '' : { // targeting unnamed ui-view=""
      templateUrl: 'tpl.hello2.html',
    }
  }
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nK8zLLidwjTAUe3kEwFZ?p=preview)